# Isc Dhcp-allow only 1 lease from opt82 tag

Tags: dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I'm implementing an isc dhcp server that will be utilizing option 82 tags from our switches to hand out dhcp information/addresses I'd like to deny multiple requests with the same tag (if someone decides to connect a switch to our switch to have multiple devices...) is this possible? If so can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at `PER-CLASS LIMITS ON DYNAMIC ADDRESS ALLOCATION` and `SPAWNING CLASSES` sections in dhcpd.conf man page.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!